# What does fire mean in the context of "divided tongues, as it were of fire" (Acts 2:3)?

Tags: word-study, acts, context, terminology

Acts 2:3 (YLT):

> 3 and there appeared to them **divided tongues, as it were of fire**; it sat also upon each one of them,

What does fire mean in this context? And how is the fire related to the divided tongues? How should we make sense of the individual words and the full expression as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

The sense of Acts 2:2, 3 is rather simple:

- the Holy Spirit was the single source of all that they observed
- the fire of the Holy spirit divided and settled on the individuals

Thus, the divided tongues were simply an indication that they all received supernatural ability from the same single source, namely, the Holy Spirit.  This is emphasized in the next verse of V4:

> **2** Suddenly a sound like a mighty rushing wind came from heaven and filled the whole house where they were sitting. **3** They saw tongues
> like flames of fire that separated/divided and came to rest on each of them.
> **4** And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit enabled them.

The crucial word in V3 is ὡσεὶ (hosei) means "like" or "as" indicating that the fire was not real but only looked like fire. This is consistent with NT usage that often makes fire a symbol or metaphor of the Holy Spirit: Matt 3:11, Luke 3:16, Acts 2:3, 4, 7:30, Rom 12:11, 1 Thess 5:19, Rev 4:5, 7, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The description by Luke was a feeble attempt to explain and describe the fantastic event happening on the Day of Pentecost, a Jewish festival.  Instead of one massive *glory cloud* as had happened on several occasions in the Tanach (Christian O.T.), Luke was describing "individual flames" of glory hovering over each individual. "Fire" was another name for the Shekinah Glory of God which He was known to display on important occasions. The OUTPOURING OF THE HOLY SPIRIT on all disciples, instead of just priests and Levites, was such an occasion! This was a prophetic fulfilment of Jesus (See John 15-16), as well as an ancient prophecy given by the prophet Joel hundreds of year earlier.

The author was not referring to ordinary "fire" which consumes flammable material. And the excited disciples were not injured in any way.  *Au contraire* the disciples were filled with unspeakable joy and power to live the Christian life in the midst of a persecuting culture.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of God is often shown by fire in the OT. Note that Acts says something that looked like fire. This is reminiscent of how visions often say something "looked like" fill-in-the-blank with something from normal human experience. The appearance of something that resembled fire was just a visible manifestation of God's invisible presence with his children.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Exodus 34:28-29 Moses is up  on the  mountain (which is a portrayed as God's sacrificial altar).

> Moses was there with the Lord forty days and forty nights without
> eating bread or drinking water. And he wrote on the tablets the words
> of the covenant—the Ten Commandments. When Moses came down from Mount
> Sinai with the two tablets of the covenant law in his hands, he was
> not aware that his face was radiant because he had spoken with the
> Lord.

The word for "radiant" means shine, but also suggests sprouting horns. So Moses is portrayed not only as a powerful shining elohim coming down from heaven, but also as a sacrificial animal given on behalf of the people.

In Acts 2:1-3 Jesus' disciples had been waiting for 50 days since the death of Jesus.

> Suddenly a sound like the blowing of a violent wind came from heaven
> and filled the whole house where they were sitting. They saw what
> seemed to be tongues of fire that separated and came to rest on each
> of them.

If the word separated means separated in two, then the tongues of fire would look like horns and suggest that Christian are a sacrifice. Alternatively if it means the fire was evenly distributed to each person, would emphasise that God's power was no longer reserved for one leader.

Either way, Christians are portrayed as a new Moses bringing the terms of the new covenant between God and the world.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'as it were of fire' implies that it was not actually fire, though what it truly was remains unknown. However, the consequences of the event were widely understood by all who witnessed it;

> All of them were **filled with the Holy Spirit** and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit enabled them. (Acts 2:4 NIV)

One possibility that Luke used 'fire' to describe it may originated from the witness of John the Baptist; he said

> “I baptize you with water for repentance. But after me comes one who is more powerful than I, whose sandals I am not worthy to carry. **He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire.**" (Matthew 3:11 NIV)

It divided from one source, the Lord.